# popper.js error when including Bootstrap 4 in RequireJS config

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, requirejs, popper.js

When including Bootstrap 4 in my RequireJS config to be included in my application I get the following warning:

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://crmpicco.localhost/app/app_dev.php/en/portal/view/ksldjfkldsjfklsdjflkj/popper.js”.

and the following error:

> Error: Script error for "popper.js", needed by: bootstrap
>   https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

when using Bootstrap 4 with RequireJS/AMD and I cannot work out how to resolve it.

```
require = {
    paths: {
        jquery: '/app/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        popper: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min',
        bootstrap: '/app/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min',
    }
}
```

I have also tried dropping the `<script>` tag for popper.js right into the source before my compiled JavaScript is included, but it has no effect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by doing the following...

I am using Yarn, so I included popper.js with `yarn add popper.js`

then adjusted my RequireJS config.js:

```
require = {
    baseUrl: '/app/assets/js',
    paths: {
        jquery: '/app/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        popper: '/app/assets/vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min',
        bootstrap: '/app/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min'
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: [
                'jquery',
                'popper'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the dependencies that popper itself has.

Comment: @Jim What errors are you getting, Jim? What specific dependencies?